# Float div horizontally while scrolling horizontally - CSS / Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, datatable

I have a **DataTable** that is inside a div with `overflow: scroll`

It has approximate 25 columns. I scroll horizontally to view all column. Now I want the search bar to scroll with me while I'm scrolling. Really don't know how to explain this :) Let's see the image.

[image: Datatable]

See! While scrolling the search div is fixed. **I want to make it flow with scrolling. If possible the pagination div too.**

Question is how can do it? Searched for it, but nothing found yet. Is it possible to do it with simple css or may be some Jquery trick?

Oh! If you want to see the div css

```
.hugewidth {
    overflow-x: scroll;
    overflow-y: hidden;
    width: 100%;
}
```

**Edit:**

Here is the code for that `div` captured from **Firebug**. I don't know why this div not visible in JSFiddle. May be version problem.

```
<div id="voucher_table_length" class="dataTables_length">
     <label>Show <select name="voucher_table_length" size="1" aria-controls="voucher_table"><option value="10">10</option><option value="25">25</option><option value="50" selected="selected">50</option><option value="100">100</option><option value="200">200</option><option value="-1">All</option></select> entries</label>
</div>
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4x4qL/)

Comment: keep it out of the table and scroll only the table part.

Comment: It's created by data table plugin. How can I keep it out? @Mr_Green

Comment: sorry I am not aware about this plugin.. can you post a [fiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.net)?

Comment: @Mr_Green http://jsfiddle.net/4x4qL/

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this

```
$('.scrollDiv').scroll(function(){
    console.log($("div").scrollLeft()+" px");  // scroll postion
   var scrollPostion = $("div").scrollLeft()+" px");
  // You can set your search box margin-left = xxpx ;
  // Do the logic 

})
```

Comment: Nope...... Everything is breaking. The div that I want to float gets squeezed and elements inside them gets onto one another.

Comment: you have to rearrange your css little , i just give an example